# Why data usage increases when deleting rows Mysql Cluster?

Tags: mysql, database

My mysql cluster data nodes data usage increased to 95%. Then i tried to delete 500000 rows and my data usage of nodes started increasing initially and reached to 99% and above and TABLE FULL error is encountered. Please can anyone tell me why data usage of existing nodes increased when deleting rows? What is the internal working of mysql cluster when deleting rows?

My MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations parameter in config.ini 600000 and it is not due to this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting rows does not necessarily free up disk space. In fact, it might use up more as it keeps [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) logs and associated replication data.

In comparison, `TRUNCATE` will abandon data wholesale and doesn't seem to incur the same penalty, at least with most engines.

If you're really short on disk space, you may need to drop some tables entirely to liberate some headroom.

Comment: What are these MVCC logs and associated replication data ?
And are they kept in data memory ? And data memory definitely frees up when deleting rows but initially it always increases and then drops down suddenly. And NoOfReplicas in my case is 1.

Comment: I am using NDB engine and i was talking about my data memory usage not the disk space.

Comment: When people say "data usage" they usually mean "data stored on disk", unless you're talking about some particular parameter.

Comment: Here in mysql cluster when we execute "all report mem" on management client it shows data usage and index usage and here data usage signifies "the data memory used on that node"... please explain what is the whole procedure when it deletes rows in mysql cluster ??